# How do I add an external library in Android?

Tags: android

I want to add a library as module to my Android project. I've read some of the answer and tried them but still it shows a error during gradle sync. I've added libraries as JAR files before but not as modules.

Comment: https://medium.com/@deepakpk/how-to-add-a-git-android-library-project-as-a-sub-module-c713a653ab1f may be this would help.

Comment: "trided multiple times" -- then provide a [mcve] demonstrating **specifically** what you tried and what **specifically** is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to project directory

right click

new

module

there you can select correct type of module that you want add
and sync the project

right click on app module

Open Module Settings

app

Dependency

plus

Module